# Website not showing data after upgrading to EF 5.0.1/DbContextFactory

Tags: entity-framework-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm writing a web app to submit videos for voting.
Because I ran into problems with threading and databases, I upgraded from core 3.0.1 to 5.0.1

Before I was using the services.AddDbContext, which did not work. now I'm using this:

```
  services.AddDbContextFactory<LogicDbContext>(
            dbContextOptions => dbContextOptions
                .UseMySql(serverVersion: ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connectionString), connectionString: connectionString)
                .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
                .EnableDetailedErrors());
```

My frontend:

```
@page "/VideoPage"
@using WebProject.Data
@using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.Data
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics
@using System.Security.Claims
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore
@using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
@inject YoutubeApiService YoutubeApiService;
@inject SignInManager<IdentityUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<IdentityUser> UserManager
@inject VideoManager VideoManager;
@inject VoteManager VoteManager;
@inject ApplicationDbContext _identityContext

<h1>Videos</h1>

<div style="visibility: @(busy?"visible":"hidden")">
    <text>
        Working...
    </text>
</div>

<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Thumbnail</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Channel</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Submitter</th>
            <th>Votes</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var video in VideosList)
        {
            <tr>
                <td><img src="@video.Thumbnail" alt="Thumbnail not found" width="200" /></td>
                <td><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=@video.VideoId">@video.Title</a></td>
                <td>@video.ChannelTitle</td>
                <td>@video.PublicationDate?.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")</td>
                <td>@_identityContext.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == video.Submitter)?.UserName</td>
                <td>
                    @(VoteManager.GetVotesAsync(video).Result)
                </td>
            </tr>

        }
    </tbody>
</table>

@code
{
    public List<Videos> VideosList = new List<Videos>();
    public bool busy;

    protected override async void OnInitialized()
    {
        await RefreshList();
    }

    public async Task RefreshList()
    {
        busy = true;
        VideosList = await VideoManager.GetVideosAsync();
        busy = false;
        this.StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

VoteManager

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using WebProject.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace WebProject.Data
{
    public class VideoManager
    {
        private readonly IDbContextFactory<LogicDbContext> _contextFactory;
        private readonly YoutubeApiService _youtubeApiService;

        public VideoManager(IDbContextFactory<LogicDbContext> contextFactory, YoutubeApiService youtubeApiService)
        {
            _contextFactory = contextFactory;
            _youtubeApiService = youtubeApiService;
        }

        public async Task<List<Videos>> GetVideosAsync()
        {
            
            var videos = new List<Videos>();
            await using (var context = _contextFactory.CreateDbContext())
            {
                videos = await context.Videos.ToListAsync();
            }
            return videos;
        }


    }
}
```

Before changing to the new version and using the factory, the code could get the list of videos and show them.

Now after I enter the page the  "working..." message is shown and nothing more happens. when debugging in VS (I'm not using VS code) it tells me that VideoList is in fact populated. Also busy is set to false.
Using `this.StateHasChanged();` does nothing. Sometimes the whole website freezes and I can't even click on links.

Is there anything I'm not seeing?

Comment: I spot some errors in your code.  You have async void OnInitialized, which is incorrect.  You should override async Task OnInitializedAsync().  Then, you should not access VideoList before you are sure the list gets populated. I suggest you do not initialize it, because you aways assign a new instance to it.  Better leave it to null and rend the table only when the VideoList has a value.

Comment: Could you explain why VideoLists should be null? Is it a performance issue?

Comment: `i ran into problems with threading and databases,` what problem? EF Core 3.1 has no threading issues. If your code uses bad access patterns, upgrading the ORM won't fix them. A DbContext is *not* thread-safe by design. It's not a connection to be reused, it's a Unit-of-Work

Comment: `i was using the services.AddDbContext, wich did not work` what didn't work? Which MySQL provider are you using? Oracle's provider is notorious for its bugs and somewhat ... delayed updates. Oracle has no interest in supporting .NET Core after all. That's why people use the open-source Pomelo driver instead.

Comment: More problems - `async void` is *only* meant for event handlers. `OnInitialized` isn't an event handler. You need to use `async Task OnInitializedAsync` instead. `async void` methods can't be awaited which means the application will keep running even if `RefreshList` is still running. By the time it completes, the page is already rendered and sent to the browser

Comment: Changing it to async Task OnInitializedAsync doesnt change anything

Comment: Im using Mysql from Pomelo
I always got an exception because two threats were using the same context. I dont understand why I had this problem. when using DI to get the context there is only one instance. how am i supposed to use it then? in the videomanager there is a DI context in the constructor. how do i use the manager? do i inject it in the frontend or do i create a new instance everytime?

Comment: there are no exceptions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with

```
<td>
  @(VoteManager.GetVotesAsync(video).Result)
</td>
```

You can't `await` in the Blazor (Razor) code and `.Result` is the culprit, it can block the main thread, resulting in deadlock. That matches your symptoms.

The rule is to always avoid `.Result` and `.Wait()` in async code.

As a solution, just `.Include()` the votes when you get the videos.  Doing 1 big query  also gives better performance than many smaller ones.